# "E2597 SysInit.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format" when compiling a 32-bit Android app

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I get this error when trying to compile a 32-bit Android application:

> [DCC Error] E2597 c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\Android\debug\SysInit.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

When compiling for 64-bit, there is no problem.

I have tried reinstalling the Android platform, and using a different SDK version, but the issue is the same.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Codex. Certainly more info is needed as what Delphi version are you using (looks like 10.4) and if you were able to compile successfully in the past. Some things you could try: compile an empty project, compile in Debug/Release, and check if something changes.

Comment: @AlexSawers Yes I did use delphi 10.4, no I did not try to compile in 32-Bit in the past, only 64-Bit which worked, I tried switching between debug/release, I tried compiling a empty project and I tried compiling with different android versions. Unfortunately none of these attempts fixed the issue, the error remained the same.

Comment: Please check your NDK settings for Android 32bit by going to Tools > Options > Deployment > SDK Manager > Android SDK 25.5.5 32-bit > NDK tab. These should look like [this image](https://i0.wp.com/delphiworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2020-09-06_14-11-09.png?ssl=1), especially the paths _after_ the `android-ndk-r21` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error in Delphi 11, to fix it access the tab NDK in Android SDK 32bits (SDK Manager), then modify the path for:
arm-linux-androideabi-id.exe
arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe
gdbserver location
C++ Builder NDK library path
Delphi NDK library path.

In my computer is like this:

**arm-linux-androideabi-id.exe**
*C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe*

**arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe**
*C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe*

**gdbserver location**
*C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver*

**C++ Builder NDK library path**
*C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-23\arch-arm\usr\lib*

**Delphi NDK library path.**
*C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.44500.8973\android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-23\arch-arm\usr\lib*

**This should be different depending on the version and how the installation was performed.**